# What if I close a wallet program in midst of a transaction?

Tags: transactions, network, peers

Suppose I start a transaction in my wallet program (such as Mist or MetaMask).

Also suppose the transaction is delayed (for example because of being connected to zero peers) and I exit from the program, while the transaction is not yet delivered.

Will the program continue to work to send the transaction after I restart the program?

Is it OK to exit from the program in midst of a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on your wallet/node implementation.

For example old versions of geth didn't keep a list of pending transactions. So if the node crashed or have to be restarted the no yet delivered transactions were lost. Current versions keep a list of your pending transactions and on restart it will try to send the again.